# Slider bar math help needed see inside

Tags: c++, math, qml

Hey all i stink at math here's what i want to do in QML:

I have a slider bar that I want the min left edge to be 30 and the max right edge to be 100

what math puts 30 on the left end but gives all the percentages in between 30-100 to reflect 0-100% on the screen?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a value between `30` and `100`:

```
percent = 100 * (value - 30) / 70
```

Or more generally:

```
percent = 100 * (value - min) / (max - min)
```